# Brownian motion and relation within variance and the velocity autocorrelation function

Tags: brownian-motion, variance, correlation

The question is:
how to prove that for a particle that follows a brownian motion we have:
$$
\langle  X(t)^2 \rangle = 2\int_{0}^{t}d\tau\ (t-\tau)C_{v}(\tau) = 2\int_{0}^{t}d\tau_1\int_{0}^{\tau_1}C_{v}(\tau)d\tau
$$
where $X(t)$ is the random position of the particle and $C_{v}(\tau) = \langle  V(t_1)V(t_1+\tau) \rangle$ is the velocity autocorrelation function, with of course $\frac{dX(t)}{dt}=V(t)$.

**Remark**

To avoid confusion, the Brownian Motion is intended here with the physical interpretation, similar to the original one: it is a bivariate Markov process $(X(t),V(t))$ where $V(t)=\frac{dX}{dt}$ and $V$ satisfy the following Langevin equation: $\frac{dV}{dt}= A(t)$ where $A(t)$ is a white noise random process: $\langle A(t) \rangle = 0$ and $\langle A(t)A(t') \rangle = \sigma^2\delta(t-t')$. So $X(t)$ is the process that defines the position of the particle, $V(t)$ is the process that define the velocity of the particle and the Langevin equation is like the "Newton's" law of dynamics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I solved it.
We have that
$$
X(t)=\int_{0}^{t}V(t_1)dt_1
$$
 and so 
$$
\langle  X(t)^2 \rangle =\int_{0}^{t}\int_{0}^{t}\langle V(t_1)V(t_2)\rangle dt_1dt_2 = \int_{0}^{t}\int_{0}^{t}C_{v}(t_2-t_1)dt_1dt_2
$$ 
The last equality is because the Brownian motion is a stationary process. Remember also that the velocity autocorrelation function is an even function of $t$, i.e $C_{v}(t_2-t_1)=C_{v}(t_1-t_2)$.

Now let
\begin{align}
\tau & = t_2-t_1 \\
T & = t_1+t_2
\end{align}
So that
\begin{align}
t_2 & = \frac{\tau+T}{2} \\
t_1 & =\frac{T-\tau}{2} \\
\end{align}
The Jacobean of this transformation is $1/2$ and the integral becomes:
$$
\langle  X(t)^2 \rangle =\frac{1}{2}\left[\int_{0}^{t}C_{v}(\tau)d\tau\int_{\tau}^{2t-\tau}dT+\int_{-t}^{0}C_{v}(\tau)d\tau\int_{-\tau}^{2t+\tau}dT\right] = \int_{0}^{t}(t-\tau)C_{v}(\tau)d\tau+\int_{-t}^{0}(t+\tau)C_{v}(\tau)d\tau=2\int_{0}^{t}(t-\tau)C_{v}(\tau)d\tau
$$ 
as required. I change $\tau=-\tau$ in the second integral and I use the parity of the VAF: $C(\tau)=C(-\tau)$.

Now integrating by part we have also:
$$
2\int_{0}^{t}(t-\tau)C_{v}(\tau)d\tau = 2\int_{0}^{t}d\tau_1\int_{0}^{\tau_1}C_{v}(\tau)d\tau
$$

**Remark**

The relation $X(t)=\int_{0}^{t}V(t_1)dt_1$ holds because the process $V(t)$, although not differentiable, is continuous (as, for instance, it satisfy the stochastic equation $\Delta V \propto \Delta t^{1/2}\Delta W $, where $\Delta W$ is an uncorrelated stationary Gaussian process with zero mean) and so it is integrable.

Comment: Note how the very definition of $X(t)$, from which your own answer is starting, was impossible to guess from the text of your question. Thus...

Comment: Sorry I don't understand...was it not clear that $X(t)$ is the random position of a particle that follows a Brownian motion?

Comment: No it was not. Amongst other reasons, because this is not how you define X(t) in your answer.

Comment: Maybe now it is better.

Comment: So now we know for sure that X(t) **cannot** be Brownian motion...

Comment: Sorry but I really don't understand what do you mean. I read the question's identity in a text about brownian motion and I just asked for a proof. I wrote the question using the same notation of the book. I don't know if my answer is correct, but it seems so to me.

Comment: If really "it seems so to you", you should check the definition of Brownian motion. If you do *that*, using serious sources, one of the first things you might stumble upon is that Brownian motion is *not* differentiable, hence the formula $X(t)=\int_0^tV(s)ds$ makes no sense for a Brownian motion.

Comment: Yes, sorry I just start to study this field. But Brownian motion could mean the stochastic processes $(x(t), v(t))$ where $v(t)$ follows a Langevin equation with a random force (white noise). So $V(t)$ is not differentiable but is continuous and so it is integrable. Anyway thanks for your patience!

Comment: ?? ...And then X(t) would definitely not be a Brownian motion.

Comment: Well, what I mean is that the Brownian motion, that informally I called with $X(t)$ in the first version of the question, is the physical motion $(X(t),V(t))$, i.e the random motion of particles. The velocity follows $d(V)/dt = F(t)/m$ where F(t) is a random force with $<F>=0$ and $<F(t_1)F(t_2)>=\sigma^2\delta(t_1-t_2)$. So only $V(t)$ is not differentiable. I don't mean with Brownian motion the Wiener process. Is my answer right or not?